# rename key in mongoose response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using **NodeJS** and **mongoose**.

I have two collections named **profiles** and **businesses** with following schema.

```
ProfileSchema = new Schema ({
    first_name: {type: String, required: true},
    last_name: {type: String, required: true},
    age: {type: Number, required: true},
    business_ids: [
         {type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'business'}
    ]
});
```

Similarly,

```
BusinessSchema = new Schema ({
        title: {type: String, required: true},
        type: {type: String, required: true},
        address: {type: String, required: true},        
    });
```

A sample response when i query **profile** is

```
profiles.find().populate("business_ids")
```

returns

```
{
  "_id": "5bf5fbef16a06667027eecc2",
  "first_name": "Asad",
  "last_name": "Hayat",
  "age": "26",
  "business_ids": [
    {
      "_id": "5ae14d2e124da839884ff939",
      "title": "Business 1",
      "type": "B Type",
      "address": "Business 1 Address"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5ae14d2e124da839884ff93b",
      "title": "Business 2",
      "type": "C Type",
      "address": "Business 2 Address"
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0
}
```

I want the **business_ids** field to remain same in collection, but rename it to **businesses** in my query responses. How can i achieve this.

Comment: It is important that that you share all relevant code that you currently have in place. That way, it is possible to help solve your issue. 
With that in mind - you mention your query, please share the code of your query.

Comment: I guess the simplest way would be the rename the field as business_ids :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the aggregate pipeline with `$lookup` instead of find with populate

something like this

```
db.profile.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "business",
      localField: "business_ids",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "businesses"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      business_ids: 0 // this is to remove the business_ids array of ObjectIds, if you want to keep it, you can omit this $project step
    }
  }
])
```

you can test it here [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PKWNZvTklpP)

hope it helps